# I am trying to replace a string with another string

Tags: javascript

So when I type:

```
function x(z) {
    if (z !== 'y') return ("There is an error!")

    z = z.replace(/y/g, 'Canada');

    return x(z);
}

x('y')
```

I receive make "There is an error". But I am trying to get it to say 'Canada'.

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `return x(z);` by `return z;`

Comment: I'm not convinced this is worthy of 5 downvotes? Could the voters explain? It's basic but not badly explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Liam I think they downvoted because this question is not clear enough, don't mind them! As long this user get good answers and your question is solved :)\

Comment: It's not my question... @C0dekid.php :)

Comment: Oh I see @Liam, I have edited my comment, sorry! haha :)

Comment: @AndyLe It is down voted because it is not clearly explained. The main reason is because "replacing a string with a string" can be done like this: `myStr = "new stuff"`. That replaces the value of the string myStr with another string, which is word for word what you asked for. So there is clearly something you want to do besides just replacing a string with a string. Explain what you really want to accomplish. Another reason is because you have an if statement in the first line of your function that is not explained, very odd, and has no obvious reason for being there.

Answer (score 7):

You are unnecessarily making a `recursive` call there,

```
function x(z) {
  if (z !== 'y') return ("There is an error!")
  z = z.replace(/y/g, 'Canada');
  return z;
}
```

That is not required at all in your context.

Comment: Hehe I only spotted this after your post! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do.

```
function x(z) {
    if (z !== 'y') return ("There is an error!")

    z = z.replace(/y/g, 'Canada');

    return z;
}

alert(x('y')); // Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary call to x(z). See below

```
function x(z) {
    if (z !== 'y') return ("There is an error!");

    z = z.replace(/y/g, 'Canada');

    return z; // changed from return x(z), unnecessary recursion
}

console.log(x('y'));
```

Comment: Please close `x('y')`, `return ("There is an error!")` and `return z` with a `;`

Comment: x('y') here is shown as example. I usually test all my scripts inside the browsers script panel.

Comment: It works, but it can causes errors with other scripts if not closed properly. This only a tip ;) @Samundra

Comment: I understand your concern and I have made changes as per your suggestion. The script now logs output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Because `z` is already replaced with `Canada` at the second execution of the recursion. BTW, there is no point to use regex in your case.

```
function x(z) {
    if (z !== 'y') return ("There is an error!")
    z = z.replace('y', 'Canada');
}
x('y')
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is doing exactly what you are telling it to.

You're saying: return "There is an error!" if var z is not equal to 'y', otherwise call the same function with a value not equal to 'y'.

Then you're call the function with 'y'.